# iOS Charts possibility to rotate a bar chart x-axis label around a different anchor point other than its center

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Dears,

I want to achive rotating an x-axis label on a bar chart by 45 degree.
That's currently possible with using like this:

```
chartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -45
```

And the result is: 
[Bar chart labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqRFp.png)

As you see, the rotating anchor point is exactly the center points of the labels.

But i need to rotate them around their very right corner. So, it prevents overlapping each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have an easy way to change the rotating anchor point of the labels.
But you can define your own custom `XAxisRenderer` class and override `renderAxisLabels` function. I have made a simple example and hope this will help you to move in the right direction. I have removed all unnecessary code from `renderAxisLabels` function and changed anchor point from (x: 0.5, y: 0.0) to (x: 0.8, y: 0.0)

Define custom renderer

```
class MyXAxisRenderer: XAxisRenderer {
    override func renderAxisLabels(context: CGContext)
    {
        guard let xAxis = self.axis as? XAxis else { return }

        if !xAxis.isEnabled || !xAxis.isDrawLabelsEnabled
        {
            return
        }

        let yOffset = xAxis.yOffset

        guard xAxis.labelPosition == .bottom else { return  }

        let customAnchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 0.0)  // custom anchor point, default value is (x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

        drawLabels(context: context, pos: viewPortHandler.contentBottom + yOffset, anchor: customAnchorPoint)
    }
}
```

and use it.

```
chartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -45
chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom      
chartView.xAxisRenderer = MyXAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler: chartView.viewPortHandler, xAxis: chartView.xAxis, transformer: chartView.getTransformer(forAxis: .left))
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Solved elegantly! Many thanks. I am just curious about how CGPoint(x:0.8,y:0.0) means the right end side of a label. I will do my own research, but if there is a short explanation, i would like to hear about it.

Comment: @nostromo821 Actually CGPoint(x:0.8,y:0.0) doesn't mean the right end side of a label. I have used this solution to avoid deep diving into details of labels drawing implementation.